# servlet show only one data from database not all

Tags: java, servlets

```
public static getset getdata(){
        getset gs=new getset();
     byte img[]=null;   
     ServletOutputStream sos=null;

    try {
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db","root","admin");
PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement("select * from emp");
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();

while(rs.next()){
   gs.setId(rs.getInt(1));
   gs.setName(rs.getString(2));
   gs.setCountry(rs.getString(3));
   gs.setImg(rs.getBytes(4));

}
}catch(Exception e){System.out.print(e);}

    return gs;
    }


         NewClass nc=new NewClass();
         getset a=nc.getdata();
         out.println(a.getId());
         out.println(a.getName());
         out.println(a.getCountry());
         out.println("<img src="+a.getImg()+" width=300 height=300></img>");
```

above is my code for retriving data form database
when i rum the code it show me only one data i.e the last data from database 
and when i use (if condition ) it shows me first column data why? i cannot understand while i searched but did not found any solution .

getset is the class for getter and setter.

Comment: `gs` is always the same object. You retrieve all the values, but in the while loop you overwrite the values. That's why you eventually get only the last.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating only one object , and in the while loop overwriting it every time instead of creating a new object.

```
getset gs=new getset();
```

You should create a new object in the while loop every time, set the values and then add  the object to a list for example. Then iterate and print that list to test how it goes.

So, this should be the first statement in the loop `gs=new getset();` (if you have gs declared outside of the loop and set to null) and then add gs to a list at the end of the loop (inside, not outside).

Comment: Consider accepting the answer that you found the most useful.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting/saving only **one** object inside while/if,

When using `if`, you are entering at the first time only

When entering `while` loop, you are overriding values until the last data update.

For getting multiple values add data to `List` for example